# Compare two collection values c#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, collections, reference

I have two collection with same values,but they are with different reference. What would be the best approach to compare the two collection without foreach statement,
Below is sample application i created,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;

namespace CollectionComparer
{
  public class Program
  {
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var persons = GetPersons();
        var p1 = new ObservableCollection<Person>(persons);
        IList<Person> p2 = p1.ToList().ConvertAll(x =>
            new Person
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Age = x.Age,
                Name = x.Name,
                Country = x.Country
            });

        //p1[0].Name = "Name6";
        //p1[1].Age = 36;

        if (Equals(p1, p2))
            Console.WriteLine("Collection and its values are Equal");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Collection and its values are not Equal");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Person> GetPersons()
    {
        var persons = new List<Person>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var p = new Person
            {
                Id = i,
                Age = 20 + i,
                Name = "Name" + i,
                Country = "Country" + i
            };
            persons.Add(p);
        }
        return persons;
    }
  }
}

public class Person
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }
  public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

In the code above i need to compare collection p1 and p2. But the result always comes as "Collection and its values are not equal" since both collection are of different reference.
Is there a generic way to do this kind of comparision without using foreach and comparing the type specific properties.

Comment: you could override `Equals` for your `Person` class

Comment: Why you don't wantto use a foreach loop? What about a for loop?

Comment: Is order important or do you want to check that both collections have the same persons in whichever order?

Comment: For example, you have two `List<Person>` `p1` and `p2`.
`var areEqual = p1.All(p => p2.Contains(p);`

Comment: Order here is not important. I just want to check if an item is added, deleted or edited in one collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ICompareable interface and implement your own compare function. You can refer to the following link https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Enumerable.SequenceEqual<T>(IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second)`.

This will compare both sequences *in order* and return `true` if the items contained within are equal, and both have the same number of elements.

One caveat, because `Person` does not override `Equals(object obj)`, `SequenceEqual` will perform the default *reference equality check* when comparing any two `Person` objects, and you probably want value equality semantics. To fix this, at least, override `bool Equals(object obj)` and `int GetHashCode()` (it is consider a good practice to also implement `IEquatable<Person>`):

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
         var person = obj as Person;

         if (person == null) return false;

         return person.Id == Id && person.Name = Name && //etc.
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() 
        => Id.GetHashCode() ^ Name.GetHashCode() ^ //etc.
}
```

If you can't modify `Person`, then you can define your own `IEqualityComparer<Person>` and hand that down to `SequenceEquals` so it can perform equality checks other than the default reference equality.

*UPDATE*: if the order is not important, then you can use [`Union`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx). This can get slow pretty fast, so you should at least consider the possibility of converting the collections you are comparing into some type of `Set` before.

*UPDATE2*: `Enumerable.SequenceEqual` is in fact an *extension* method and should be called as such: `p1.SequenceEquals(p2)`

Comment: I think the above code can be used, but the above scenario both collection sequence should be same. But in my collection the sequence may vary.

Comment: Thanks for the help, This "Except" works fine when i have value types, But dosent work for reference type properties. Example in the same Person class if i change the Id to Guid. This comparision dosent work. Is there any way to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but perhaps I can make someone's day easier. After searching for a way to compare two ObservableCollections, where T has numerous properties, my final solution was to JSON serialize both objects and compare the string results.
This worked well for me with very little code involved. Granted in my case the collections started out identical and I am only interested in edits made for the purpose of flagging the dirty status.